# Does the body of the MOSFET consume current?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Does the body of the MOSFET consume power and pass current if it weren't grounded? Like if I had a body bias and the value of Vsb wasn't zero, so in this case the diode inside the MOSFET must pass some current? Does it or not? And if it does, where does this current go and doesn't it make the MOSFET heat up?

Comment: No component consume current. Current just pass through components: what comes in goes out. What is consumed is *power*. And yes, a component consuming power will heat up.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at an NMOS sideview:

[image]

Realize that an PN-junction is a diode. So there is a diode between Source (anode) and Body (cathode) and a second diode between Drain (anode) and Body (cathode).

For normal operation we want these diodes **not** to be in forward mode which means \$V_{sb}\$ and \$V_{db}\$ should not be negative (drain and/or source having a lower voltage than Body).

So your question is, what happens if we do violate that rule ?

Well then these diodes can operate in forward mode! What really happens as a consequence of that depends on the actual situation (circuit, voltages etc.). Fact is that while normally all current flowing through the NMOS will enter at the Drain and leave at the Source.

This will no longer be the case when one of the body diodes operates in forward mode. Part of the current will then "escape" via the body (substrate). That current will then follow a different current loop, the current is not lost nor is it "consumed". How much current that will be depends on many factors like, (forward) voltage across the diode, drain current, substrate doping level (that influences the resistance of the substrate).

The current through the substrate will cause a voltage drop and just like with every other diode, power will be dissipated. So yes, the body/substrate will heat up. By how much depends on the amount of power that is dissipated and what the thermal resistance to the outside world is.

You should realize that Drain-Body and Source-Body diodes behave just like any other diode so current will flow when in forward and power will be dissipated. These diodes do not have a "magic" property which makes them different from other diodes. Think about this: would it make sense for a diode **not** to conduct current when in forward mode or would it make sense that it **does not** dissipate power when clearly it is consuming power because there is a forward voltage and a current.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen transient effects, with drain slew_rates of 1 volt per nanosecond, where the induced I = C * dV/dT causes enough voltage drop in the substrate to trigger the parasitic bipolar.
[notice in the diagram provided by Blimpelrekkie there is a lateral NPN, with the **base** being bulk/well/substrate/tub.]

If the current is not limited (tickling the dragon, I call it), then the FET/bipolar becomes a fuzed mass of silicon.

Cure was to update the layout rules, and capture more of that transient current into substrate/well ties.

Failure voltages improved by 50%.

The travails of undocumented inherited highly-profitable semiconductor processes and products.

Would being "grounded" help with this? No. There is no way to get under the FET, within a few microns of where the transient currents were injected, and grab ahold of the silicon, without massive and expensive changes to the process.

Comment: I believe that this answer is way beyond the comprehension level of OP and as such of little use to him/her. Before one can understand the lateral NPN one should be able to dream the B/S diodes.